# Does Sitecore 9 scheduled publishing publish not only an item but also its child and related items?

Tags: sitecore

In Sitecore 7, if I put a scheduled publish on an item, which has children and related items, the item is published correctly, but its child items and related items are not published. Does Sitecore 9 scheduled publishing publish not only an item but also its child and related items correctly? If so, we will migrate to Sitecore 9, instead of spending a lot of time and energy on building custom code and items to make scheduled publishing work correctly. I googled but couldn't find answers to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely speaking about [PublishAgent](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10635/how-to-add-multiple-publish-agent) that is launched periodically (like every hour), and does `Smart` publish (publishes any difference between master & live).

The scheduled publish is usually achieved via [publishing restrictions](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/set-up-publishing-restrictions-for-an-item.html#UUID-d79d3956-f906-8676-2048-3e9c0c53720c_id__Publishing_restrictions_for_body) so that item becomes eligible to be published only after configured time (saying by midnight).

The [PublishAgent](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10635/how-to-add-multiple-publish-agent) would be running regularly and publish everything that is eligible. Should item kids had been `unpublishible` as parent was not publishable, they would be published along with parent.

The likely answer to your question - yes.